# How to get incoming SIP call information (like SIP headers and etc) in MS Teams Bot callback?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Our PBX enrich SIP call with some metadata (SIP headers for now) that we want to retrieve in our MS Teams bot incoming call callback.
We see in logs that these headers received by SBC. But nothing appears in the HTTP callback request headers or call info.
How can we get this type of data?

Tried: Sent SIP headers from PBX to SBC then to MS Teams.
Expected: receive HTTP headers with same values as SIP headers

Comment: Currently, this scenario is not supported.

Could you please help by suggesting this feature on - Microsoft Teams · Community[https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472]